# Flask, SQLAlchemy, SQLite - querying datetime column submitted today

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a simple daily time recording app, that updates the table row upon submitting.

Here's what I mean, suppose a staff timed-in in the morning, then my table row would be like this:

| id | time_in_am | time_out_am | time_in_pm | time_out_pm | staff_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-09 08:17:07.27 | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *223-8881* |

and upon submitting or scanning an id again, then it would update *time_out_am*, until the end of the day which is *time_out_pm*.

My problem then starts here, how would I know if the staff with an id no. of *223-8881* already clocked in today?

I've tried this:

```py
today_dt = datetime(datetime.today().year, datetime.today().month, datetime.today().day)

# check if staff clocked in today
dtr_log = DailyTimeRecord.query.filter(DailyTimeRecord.time_in_am==today_dt, staff_id=staff.id).first()
# end check
```

using the above code, I get the error:  `TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'staff_id'`
and if I use *filter_by()*, I get this: `filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

heres my model if it helps:

```py
class DailyTimeRecord(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time_in_am = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
    time_out_am = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
    time_in_pm = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
    time_out_pm = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
    staff_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('staff.id'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `filter` you need to specify the model and use 'proper' comparisons e.g: the `staff_id=staff.id` should be `DailyTimeRecord.staff_id==staff.id` so would look like:

```
dtr_log = DailyTimeRecord.query.filter(
    DailyTimeRecord.time_in_am==today_dt, 
    DailyTimeRecord.staff_id==staff.id
).first()
```

If you were using the `filter_by` helper it would look like:

```
dtr_log = DailyTimeRecord.query.filter(
    time_in_am=today_dt, 
    staff_id=staff.id
).first()
```

But you'll also run into a problem with the date comparison.  `time_in_am` is a `datetime`, and you're building a datetime to compare with, but essentially your `today_dt`  is a datetime at midnight (the hour, min, sec will default to zero because you didn't give them a value).

You really want to just deal with a date to date comparison-- so would want to cast the database value to also be a date to do what you mention, so with `filter`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from datetime import date

today_dt = date.today()

dtr_log = DailyTimeRecord.query.filter(
    func.date(DailyTimeRecord.time_in_am)==today_dt, 
    DailyTimeRecord.staff_id==staff.id
).first()
```